# Error when trying to obtain upload URL from huawei api connect

Tags: powershell, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

I've successfully obtained the api key from huawei by creating a API client on the huawei connect portal (This was created by specying the name, N/A in project field and Assigned roles as administrator)

However when I try to call the API to obtain the upload URL so that I can upload my app to the store it returns with the following error : {"ret":{"code":205524993,"msg":"client token auth failed"}}

This is my powershell script I'm using to do this:

```
#obtaining API key

$tokenHeader = @{
    "Content-Type"="application/json"
}

# Token request payload
$tokenRequest = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = $ClientId 
    client_secret = $ClientKey 
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Get Access Token
write-host "retrieving access token"
$accessTokenResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $authUrl -Method POST -Headers $tokenHeader -Body $tokenRequest

#obtaining Upload url 

    $url = "https://connect-api.cloud.huawei.com/api/publish/v2/upload-url/appId=$appId&suffix=aab"
    $headers = @{
        "client_id" = "$clientId"
        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessTokenResponse.content"
    }
    
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers
```

Comment: Can you share the code you used to obtain the access token?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, [update your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77907339/edit) with the code instead. You also need to show how you get `$accessToken` from `$accessTokenReponse`

Comment: i've added the code to my original post now, thank you

Comment: Alright, that makes sense now. Change `"Bearer $accessTokenResponse.content"` to `"Bearer $(($accessTokenResponse.Content |ConvertFrom-Json).access_token)"`